# Visualizing Stratigraphy as a Stacked Bar Graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I'm an R novice and was trying to visualize stratigraphic data as a stacked bar graph in R. I have encountered two problems that I was hoping for help with. 1) How do you orient the stacking of the bars to be Layer A, B, then C from top to bottom. 2) I've been using Cwickham's https://github.com/cwickham/munsell munsell package for R to get colours that match in field observations but it doesn't seem to be selecting the right values? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've attached my current code and result pictures below.

Here's the data read as a CSV file.
[CSV data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhNKv.png)

```
##Visualize Stratigraphy Test ###

#Load Libraries
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(munsell)


ST1 <- data.frame(
  Name=rep(c("ST1", "ST2"), each=3),
  Layer=rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2),
  DepthCM=c(8,23,42,10,20,60),
  Colour= rep(c("5 YR 4/3", "10 YR 5/3", "10 YR 5/4"), 2)
)
MunsellPalette <- c("5YR 4/3", "10YR 5/3", "10YR 5/4") #select layers 1, 2,3,etc.

#Plot Line Graph (Unannotated)
p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=ST1, aes(x= Name, y= DepthCM, fill= Layer), position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
  ggtitle("Stratigraphy") +  #Change Title
  theme_gray() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 1, colour = "black"), aspect.ratio = 1, plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15))+
  scale_y_reverse (expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = MunsellPalette)
ggsave(file="ST1Strat.png", dpi = 600)
p1
```

Current result:
[image: Current Result image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `forcats::fct_rev(Layer)` to reverse the order of the bar segments.
2. You have to convert the munsell color values to RGB colors using `munsell::mnsl()`.

It looks like the last digit in the munsell
color name as to be a multiple of 2. I adjusted the values accordingly in
the example below. By naming the entries in `MunsellPalette` with the
corresponding `Layer` values we `scale_fill_manual()` can apply the
coloring to the correct bar segments.

```r
library(munsell)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

MunsellPalette <- 
  c(A = "5YR 4/2", B = "10YR 5/2", C = "10YR 5/4") |> 
  sapply(munsell::mnsl)

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=ST1, aes(x= Name, y= DepthCM, fill= fct_rev(Layer)), position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
  ggtitle("Stratigraphy") +  #Change Title
  theme_gray() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(linewidth = 1, colour = "black"), aspect.ratio = 1, plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15))+
  scale_y_reverse (expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = MunsellPalette)
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic and fixed problem 1 but how do I change the ordering of the stacked bar graph so Layer A is starts at 0, followed by Layer B, then Layer C. The deeper you go?

Comment: You can use `forcats::fct_rev()` to reverse the order of the bar segments. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `mnsl()` function to convert the string value into color values.

It should be something like

```
MunsellPalette <- mnsl(c("5YR 4/3", "10YR 5/3", "10YR 5/4"))
```

Though your current values throws an error:

```
Error in check_mnsl(col) :
  some colours have chromas that are not multiples of two: 3 in 5YR 4/3; 3 in 10YR 5/3
```